# Object doesn't get added correctly

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to create a priority Queue and using a comparator, but when I add the object, the last one is added and the earlier ones do not appear in the queue.

Below is the code:

```
public class CustomerCompare implements Comparator<Customer>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        if(c1.priority>c2.priority)
            return 1;
        if(c1.priority>c2.priority)
            return -1;
        return 0;

    }
}      

public class PQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Comparator<Customer> comparator = new CustomerCompare();
        PriorityQueue<Customer> queue = new PriorityQueue<Customer>(5, comparator);
        queue.add(new Customer("c1", 1));
        System.out.println("Queue is now :" + queue);
        queue.add(new Customer("c2", 7));
        System.out.println("Queue is now :" + queue);
        queue.add(new Customer("c3", 3));
        System.out.println("Queue is now :" + queue);
        queue.add(new Customer("c4", 6));
        System.out.println("Queue is now :" + queue);
        queue.add(new Customer("c5", 5));

        System.out.println("Elements in queue");
        while (true) {
            Customer currentCust = queue.poll();
            if (currentCust == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.print(currentCust.getCustomerNum() + " <-- ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is:Queue is now :[Customer{c1 1}]
    Queue is now :[Customer{c2 7}, Customer{c2 7}]
    Queue is now :[Customer{c3 3}, Customer{c3 3}, Customer{c3 3}]
    Queue is now :[Customer{c4 6}, Customer{c4 6}, Customer{c4 6}, Customer{c4 6}]
    Elements in queue
    c5 <-- c5 <-- c5 <-- c5 <-- c5

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you used `>` instead of `<` in your `compare`, change it to:

```
if (c1.priority > c2.priority)
    return 1;
if (c1.priority < c2.priority)
    return -1;
return 0;
```

**EDIT: Or quite a bit more simply:**

`return Integer.valueOf(c1.priority).compareTo(c2.priority);`

**EDIT 2: Or using Java 7:**

`return Integer.compare(c1.priority, c2.priority);`